# Images are not showing up on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, responsive-design

I've got a very weird issue, that apparently happens only on mobile devices (or devices with less width/height than normal desktop, tested on Chrome viewport rendering). Images that are on the bottom of the page are not displaying, but..

They appear in some specific moments:

- when I refresh page when the images are in viewport, they appear correctly,
- when I resize the screen, images also appear,
- when I change some css properties (doesn't matter which one, I can change existing property, add another one, or disable one) in chrome inspector they also appear

Preview picture:
[image]
This is for sure not connected with the grayscale filter, becauase I was removing that property and problem still occurs. Also I've tried to remove transitions, overflow and still no help.

Here is also the CSS class for `.partners--partner`

```
.partners--partner {
    border: 5px solid #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 144px;
    line-height: 134px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

More information about the structure and the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/8kuuyuLp/2/

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: jsfiddle would definitely help or a link to the site even

Comment: I've added link to jsFiddle

Comment: @Kamil which image is not displaying properly .>? what is the issue in fiddle.?

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara On fiddle it looks quite okay, but have you tried accessing it maybe using mobile device? Images looks like on the screenshot I've attached. Not sure if the problem is with CSS or something, because If I change the viewport size or just play with CSS properties (even if I won't change any) images magically appear..

Comment: @Kamil you can try by adding display as block or else to the image container and check if it works or not